# How to transfer data, and trim data from one multi-dimensional array to another with a condition

Tags: python

I have built a python program processing the probability of various datasets.  I input 'manually' various mean values and standard deviations, and that works, however I need to automate it so that I can upload all my data through a text or csv file.  I've got so far but now have a nested for loop query I think with indices problems, but some background follows...

My code works for a small dataset where I can manually key in 6-8 parameters working but now I need to automate it and upload various inputs of unknown sizes by csv / text file.  I am copying my existing code and amending it where appropriate but I have run into a problem.

I have a 2_D numpy-array where some probabilities have been reverse sorted.  I have a second array which gives me the value of 68.3% of each row, and I want to trim the low value 31.7% data.

I need a solution which can handle an unspecified number of rows.

My pre-existing code worked for a single one-dimensional array was

```
    prob_combine_sum= np.sum(prob_combine)

    #Reverse sort the probabilities
    prob_combine_sorted=sorted(prob_combine, reverse=True)

    #Calculate 1 SD from peak Prob by multiplying Total Prob by 68.3%
    sixty_eight_percent=prob_combine_sum*0.68269

    #Loop over the sorted list and append the 1SD data into a list 
    #onesd_prob_combine
    onesd_prob_combine=[]
    for i in prob_combine_sorted:
    onesd_prob_combine.append(i)
    if sum(onesd_prob_combine) > sixty_eight_percent:
    break
```

That worked.  However, now I have a multi-dimensional array, and I want to take the 1 standard deviation data from that multi-dimensional array and stick it in another.

There's probably more than one way of doing this but I thought I would stick to the for loop, but now it's more complicated by the indices. I need to preserve the data structure, and I need to be able to handle unlimited numbers of rows in the future.

I simulated some data and if I can get this to work with this, I should be able to put it in my program.

```
    sorted_probabilities=np.asarray([[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], 
    [87,67,54,43,32,22,16,14,2],[100,99,78,65,45,43,39,22,3], 
    [67,64,49,45,42,40,28,23,17]])
    sd_test=np.asarray([30.7215,230.0699,306.5323,256.0125])
    target_array=np.zeros(4).reshape(4,1)

    #Task transfer data from sorted_probabilities to target array on 
    condition that value in each target row is less than the value in the 
    sd_test array.

    #Ignore the problem that data transferred won't add up to 68.3%.
    My real data-sample is very big.  I just need a way of trimmining 
    and transferring.


    for row in sorted_probabilities:
        for element in row:
        target_array[row].append[i]
        if sum(target[row]) > sd_test[row]:
            break
```

Error: IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

I know it's not a very good attempt. My problem is that I need a solution which will work for any 2D array, not just one with 4 rows.

I'd be really grateful for any help.

Thank you

Edit:

Can someone help me out with this?  I am struggling.

I think the reason my loop will not work is that the 'index' row I am using is not a number, but in this case a row. I will have a think about this.  In meantime has anyone a solution?

Thanks

I tried the following code after reading the comments:

```
    for counter, value in enumerate(sorted_probabilities):

        for i, element in enumerate(value):

        target_array[counter]=sorted_probabilities[counter][element]

        if target_array[counter] > sd_test[counter]:
               break
```

I get an error: IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9

I think it's because I am trying to add to numpy array of pre-determined dimensions?  I am not sure.  I am going to try another tack now as I can not do this with this approach.  It's having to maintain the rows in the target array that is making it difficult.  Each row relates to an object, and if I lose the structure it will be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use pandas. You can read directly the csv in a dataframe and do multiple operations on columns and such, clean and neat.

Comment: I want to transfer the data from one array to another processing it so that I take the top values.  WIll Pandas help with that?   I might use them later, but now I am looking for a solution.

Comment: I tried the following code:

        for counter, value in enumerate(sorted_probabilities):
            for i, element in numerate(value):rarget_array[counter]=sorted_probabilities[counter][element]
        
        if target_array[counter] > sd_test[counter]:
            break

Comment: pandas dataframe column is an array; you can create another column and put in it values with a condition:  e.g. df['newColumn'] = df[ df['oldColumn'] >= 0 ]. Check the pandas documentation, it offers many more other possibilities

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing numpy arrays with python lists. Better use only one of these (numpy is preferred). Also try to debug your code, because it has either syntax and logical errors. You don't have variable `i`, though you're using it as an index; also you are using `row` as index while it is a numpy array, but not an integer.

I strongly recommend you to

0) debug your code (at least with prints)

1) use [`enumerate`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) to create both of your `for` loops;

2) replace `append` with plain assigning, because you've already created an empty vector (`target_array`). Or initialize your `target_array` as empty list and append into it.

3) if you want to use your solution for any 2d array, wrap your code into a [function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Comment: I found the problem with using row as an index, but have been unable to resolve it through loops.  Whatever I do, seems to generate an error!  I will have a think about a function.  Thanks for reviewing.

Comment: I had a go with enumerate but still unable to do it. See my edit in main post above. Going to try a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sorted_probabilities=np.asarray([[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], 
                                 [87,67,54,43,32,22,16,14,2],
                                 [100,99,78,65,45,43,39,22,3],            
                                 [67,64,49,45,42,40,28,23,17]]
                                )
sd_test=np.asarray([30.7215,230.0699,306.5323,256.0125])
target_array=np.zeros(4).reshape(4,1)

for counter, value in enumerate(sorted_probabilities):
    for i, element in enumerate(value):
        target_array[counter] = element  # Here I removed the code that produced error
        if target_array[counter] > sd_test[counter]:
           break
```